# Portable way to check if subprocess exit code indicates a success?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, portability, exit-code

I'm looking for a **portable** way to check whether a `subprocess` exited with an exit code indicating a success.

I found out that some systems don't follow the standard convention of `0` meaning "success" (e.g. [OpenVMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#OpenVMS)) so the solution isn't as trivial as just `process.returncode == 0`.

Comment: There isn't a way other than writing your own function that checks `os.name` and/or `sys.platform` and does the proper thing.

Comment: OpenVMS used a non-zero return code to 'indicate' success because It was all to easy in the hairy-seat-of-your-pants development days for a CPU to clear the memory for a process (effectively all to '0's) in the event of a crash (usually an access violation). Success as a non-zero value was brought over from the PDP-11 Operating Systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs for `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) effectively require that `0` means success, e.g. for `subprocess.run` (the all-in-one high level synchronous API), when `check=True`, the docs specify:

> If *check* is true, and the process exits with a non-zero exit code, a `CalledProcessError` exception will be raised.

OpenVMS isn't actually a supported target for CPython, and all supported targets obey that rule to my knowledge.

Presumably the third-party OpenVMS port would have to include porting proper error-checking (even if it doesn't change the exit codes, `check=True` should be changed to make it only raise the exception when the child fails). So the simplest solution would be to write your code as:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(..., check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    # Handle failure here
```

and if OpenVMS didn't make `check=True` work the logically correct way in their port, file a bug against them to make it logically match the intended behavior (exception raised when subprocess fails, even if docs say "non-zero"). Aside from that, your only option [is checking `sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) and manually checking the error code a different way on OpenVMS (I have no idea what OpenVMS reports for `sys.platform`, you'd have to check it yourself).

Comment: I wanted to write that exceptions are not that great because you cannot get stderr or anything else prom the process. I turn out that https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError has all or at least most of the fields of process. Calling `check_returncode()` on a finished process may still be cleaner, though.

Comment: @NO_NAME: Yep, they expanded `CalledProcessError` to include all the relevant info (primarily for the benefit of `subprocess.run` with `check=True`), so if you need it, you just use `except subprocess.CalledProcessError as failedproc:` and can access relevant info on `failedproc`.